# v-autocomplete assign object to model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here is the example of v-autocomplete [`Here`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBbpWj?editors=1010)

How can i assign the object of the each item to model of the autocomplete?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to use `return-object` props of `v-autocomplete`

Like that :

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="friends"
  :disabled="isUpdating"
  :items="people"
  box
  chips
  color="blue-grey lighten-2"
  label="Select"
  item-text="name"
  return-object
  multiple>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBVeVM?editors=1010)

[Vuetify Doc about v-autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes)